# Cannot access to User.Identity under OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, authorize-attribute

I am not sure what do I am missing but I really cannot refer to 
 `User.Identity` under `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Routing;

.....

    public class RealUserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                 /// if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Any clue how to fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution.

It should be

```
filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe that you should be using AuthorizeAtribute instead of ActionFilter. Try something like this:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class AuthorizeUser : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var id = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated
```

works! and no need to check id User or User.Identity are null